# How to open Spark UI when working on Google Colab?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-colaboratory, spark-ui

How can I monitor the progress of a job through the Spark WEB UI? Running Spark locally, I can access Spark UI through the port 4040, using http://localhost:4040.

Answer (score 5):

Following this [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Tu7xeYM0qBB-RkqLSnYGrIyzb3q7bYo1#scrollTo=sDnGLVPH1BPQ) you can do the following.

First, configure the Spark UI and start a Spark session:

```py
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf


conf = SparkConf().set('spark.ui.port', '4050')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local[*]').getOrCreate()
```

In the next cell run:

```sh
!wget https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip
!unzip ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip
get_ipython().system_raw('./ngrok http 4050 &')
```

which will install `ngrok` and create a URL through which you can access the Spark UI (wait 10sec for it to start).

Now, to access the URL, call:

```sh
!curl -s http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels
```

which prints out a JSON that looks something like this (truncated):

```
{"tunnels":[{"name":"command_line","uri":"/api/tunnels/command_line","public_url":"https://1b881e94406c.ngrok.io","proto":"https", ... }
```

-- you're looking for the this `"public_url"` above, that's your Spark UI's URL.

Or, run this:

```sh
!curl -s http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels | python3 -c "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['tunnels'][0]['public_url'])"
```

I've tested it and it works for me.

Comment: I just re-visited the colab notebook and it works for me.
The last step failed initially, but that's probably because there should be a sleep that gives the UI some time to setup properly. You might simply re-run it and it should be OK.

And if it doesn't -- please let me know (what kinds of errors you're getting / what doesn't seem to work).

Comment: wait for 10-15 seconds before running !curl -s http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels

Comment: @ponadto when i click on the generated link, it takes me to a sign up page for ngrok to get an authorization token, how would I get to the interactive spark UI?

Comment: @HiraTanveer it's a paid service a with a limit on the number of URLs generated per hour (or day, not sure). The only suggestion I might have is: try to be frugal with the number of Spark UIs you generate.

Answer (score 0):

The approach can be quite short:

```py
!pip install -q pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.config('spark.ui.port', '4050').getOrCreate()

!wget -qnc https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip
!unzip -n -q ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip
get_ipython().system_raw('./ngrok http 4050 &')
!sleep 5
!curl -s http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels | grep -Po 'public_url":"(?=https)\K[^"]*'
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is basically the same as the other answer, posted a year ago

Comment: It is way shorter without unnecessary steps. Moreover, the other answer is not working standalone.

Comment: Sure. Thank you for shortening the steps, but still, running everything in the same cell kinda defeats the purpose of exploratory notebooks

Answer (score 0):

Google Colab's [`output`](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/)  library lets you view in the browser a Web server started on Colab.

You can use it like this:

```
from google.colab import output
output.serve_kernel_port_as_window(4040, path='/jobs/index.html')
```

(**important**: use the `/jobs/index.html` path otherwise this won't work!).

Since the Web UI is up only while the job is running, run a job long enough so that you have time to refresh the Web UI browser's tab.
Also important: use `spark-submit` for submitting the app (do not run it as a Python script). For instance run the `pi.py` example with:

```
! spark-submit pi.py 300
```

If that doesn't work, it might be because sometimes the Web UI gets started on port 4041 (you should see this in the app's logging messages).