# google colab - port forwarding

Tags: google-colaboratory, portforwarding

Google colab is great for the notebook - however, I want to access the user interface of a running process such as mlflow or spark from my local machine.

For the example case of spark:

```
!pip install pyspark
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[2]").getOrCreate()
spark
```

The URI to the spark UI: http://5eb11567e012:4040/ cannot be resolved in my browser.

I guess some sort of port forwarding should do the trick? A) is there a better option and B) if not, how to set up the port forwarding?

### edit

Notice: I have read some tutorials which mount the google colab directory into google drive and that one locally - but this is NOT a desired solution (and in the case of spark would not work anyways).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48459804/how-can-i-ssh-to-google-colaboratory-vm sounds promising

Comment: Indeed, using ngrok as defined https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48459804/how-can-i-ssh-to-google-colaboratory-vm works just fine

Comment: Check out my answer in a different question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64183673/783874

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [`output`](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb#scrollTo=6Ugsim80WVuq):

```
from google.colab import output
output.serve_kernel_port_as_window(4040, path='/jobs/index.html')
```

Check also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77312506/2314737) to a similar question.